# Upper to Lower Case Conversion

Tags: assembly, lc3

[View of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1aiY.png)

Write an LC-3 assembly language program to convert a letter in ASCII from upper case to lower case.  The letter (in ASCII) to be converted is stored at memory address 0x4000, and is provided in the code window below (it's the letter 'S').  The result should be stored in register 6 (R6) and also saved into memory location 0x4001.  Hint:  Due to the limited length (5 bits) of the (sign-extended) immediate field, you need more than one operate instruction to perform the conversion.

Edit:
Every time I try and run my program it gives me the same error, essentially stating that I have not done anything in the first place, I think there is an issue with the way in which I am getting my memory addresses in the first place, however, I am not sure.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: If you want debugging help, copy/paste your code into your question to make it a [mcve].  Your 2nd paragraph tells us nowhere near enough info to tell you what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this [table](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-ascii-characters-table) you will find that lowercase characters can be described like so:
the first 3 bits are always 010.
the rest of the bits signify the letter.

If you replace the first 3 bits for 010, you will get lowercase letters.

So, you need to replace the first 3 bits of the register that holds "S" with (010) to get "s".

What this code does is toggle the third bit. Uppercase thus becomes lowercase.

```
.orig x3000
; XOR:
; field is R0
; R1 is mask of bits to toggle
; R2 is scratch
LDI R0, 0x4000 ; load whatever is at x4000 into R0
LD R1, #0b00100000 ;third bit
NOT R2, R0
AND R2, R2, R1
NOT R1, R1
AND R0, R0, R1
ADD R0, R0, R2
LDI R6, R0 ;store result in R6
STI R6, .FILL x4001; store result in x4001
HALT
```

Comment: Does LC-3 really count bits starting with the MSB?  Other than PowerPC, I thought all ISAs counted bits from the bottom.  (So "5th bit set" is always the 5th bit, even if you consider it zero-extended to a 16 or 32-bit integer.)

Comment: Why is this so overcomplicated?  NOT the mask to create `11011111`, and AND with that to clear the ASCII lowercase bit, then you're done.  Or better, `ld` the inverted mask in the first place.  Or XOR with `00100000` to flip the bit instead of unconditionally clearing it.